# which verb should go before 'error' - eliminate, resolve, remove or ...?

Tags: word-choice

I edited a lot of questions in StackOverflow, but there is one thing I face in most cases: what is the best verb that comes after **error** ? I mean when I have a problem and I ask others for help to solve the problem what should I say? Should I say

> Please help me to **eliminate** the error?
>
> Please help me to **resolve** the error?
>
> Please help me to **remove** the error?

or there is a better verb for this case? (**error** here means programming bugs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [most common idiomatic phrase nowadays](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fix+the+error%2Cresolve+the+error%2Cremove+the+error%2Crectify+the+error&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfix%20the%20error%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresolve%20the%20error%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremove%20the%20error%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crectify%20the%20error%3B%2Cc0) is **fix the error**.

Comment: yup; while "correct the error" would be IMO the most common *outside* of CS, in applied sciences we generally "fix" things *chuckle*

Answer (score 4):

To [**correct**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/correct) is broadly used before **error**.

> Put right (an **error** or **fault**):

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

The linked [Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fix+the+error%2Celiminate+the+error%2Cresolve+the+error%2Cremove+the+error%2Crepair+the+error%2C+correct+the+error&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfix%20the%20error%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celiminate%20the%20error%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresolve%20the%20error%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremove%20the%20error%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crepair%20the%20error%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccorrect%20the%20error%3B%2Cc0) shows pretty big difference in each verb's usage.

1. To correct the error
2. To fix the error.
3. To eliminate the error.
4. To repair the error.
5. To remove the error.
6. To resolve the error.

Answer (score 3):

The most commonly used word would be **"Resolve"**. *'An error'* is usually a problem, to which a solution ought to be found. Thus, *'resolve'* would be the best option. There is nothing wrong in saying :

> Please help me to eliminate the error?

or

> Please help me to remove the error?

additionally, you could also say:

> Please help me to rectify the error?

But for technical usage (say, in programming or coding) of *"error"*, you should ideally use **resolve** or **remove**.

Comment: Both the other two answers include NGram links showing that *resolve the error* is ***far*** less common than either *fix* or *correct*. I don't claim there's anything actually wrong with your alternative, or that it's remotely "uncommon", but I do disagree with your claim that it's the *most* commonly used word (patently untrue), and that it's the *best* option (at best a matter of opinion, and apparently a *minority* opinion at that).